# Make HTTP/3 QUIC web request with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell Core 7.3.3 to make an HTTP/3 web request to an endpoint. However, I am pretty sure that HTTP/3 over QUIC (UDP) is not being used.

Here's the command I'm using:

```
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://quic.nginx.org/test -HttpVersion 3.0
$Result.RawContent
```

Here's the result:

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.1
Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2023 15:18:58 GMT
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
```

As you can see, the `h3` header is missing in the HTTP response.

Using Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that the request is made using HTTP/3 over QUIC.

[image]

**Question**: How do I make an HTTP/3 web request using PowerShell?

Comment: See following : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/enabling-http-3-support-on-windows-server-2022/bc-p/2801566/highlight/true?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng That doesn't help at all. That article talks about enabling HTTP/3 on a Windows Server, not making a client request from PowerShell.